# My French sister in law has money in France and needs to transfer her money to Colorado

Tags: united-states

My French sister in law has money in an account in France (Paris)
She needs to move that money to Denver, Colorado.  I live in Dallas, Texas.  Would it be easier for her to travel to Dallas and let me help her get the money?

Comment: Be aware that if currency worth more than US $10k is brought into the US, it must be _declared_ at the entry point. There is no prohibition against bringing in any amount (or any tax or Customs duty to be paid) but a declaration is needed. Why doesn’t your sister-in-law just use regular banking channels to transfer the money?

Comment: Depends on how much money we're talking about.  For small amounts - a few hundred dollars at a time, I would just use an ATM.  When I finally closed the account, the bank mailed me a check for a few thousand.

Comment: Can't she wire the money to you electronically and not physically bring it at all?

Comment: If the money’s in France, how does her going away from France let you help her get the money?